# Magento updating CMS page XML to add block - block not loading

Tags: php, xml, magento

I added a new CMS page, and editted the Layout XML to show this:

```
<reference name="head">
<block type="cms/block" name="myblock" template="myfolder/mytemplate.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

So I put the file "mytemplate.phtml" in this folder:

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/myfolder
```

And I put this test script in the file:

```
<?php
echo '<script>alert("hello");</script>';
?>
```

However, when I load the CMS page nothing happens, so it means the 'mytemplate.phtml' file is not loading.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use template (phtml), your block should extend from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

So your block type should be `core/template`, not `cms/block`.

Comment: Does that mean I need to edit some other file to extend Mage Core Block Template?? - Scrap that! I just changed it as you said and it loaded the alert :). Thanks!!

Comment: No, that means you need `type="core/template"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just display your template file, you should use block type `core/template` for that. Try this xml:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" template="myfolder/mytemplate.phtml"/>
</reference>
```